# Append Text to End of File Name for Multiple .xlsx Files in a Folder

Tags: windows, excel, vba

I have a large amount of excel files in a folder and I need to append -MN to the end of all the file names. I've looked around the web for a solution but haven't had much luck finding a clear answer.

For example:

examplefile.xlsx would become examplefile -MN.xlsx

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You haven't been too specific about your desired solution.  Is this a one-time requirement?  There are several utilities that will let you do this (Total Commander is my favourite), but if you want to do it repeatedly, you can create a macro using FileSystemObject.  It's essentially a mechanism to let your VBA act in the windows file directory structure.

Comment: Hello! Yes this is a one time requirement and work related. As far as software goes, I'm restricted from downloadnig unknown software on work laptop unless it's approved by my employer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. I changed If Right(myFileName, 5) = ".xlsx" Then to... If Right(myFileName, 4) = ".xlsx" Then

```
Sub RenameFiles()
Dim myFilePath As String, myFileName, NewFileName As String
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object

myFilePath = "C:\Temp\"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(myFilePath)
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    myFileName = objFile.Name
    If Right(myFileName, 5) = ".xlsx" Then
        NewFileName = Replace(myFileName, ".xlsx", "-MN.xlsx")
        Name myFilePath & objFile.Name As myFilePath & NewFileName
    End If
Next objFile
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello thank you for answering. This solution doesn't seem to work. I replaced C:\Temp\ with the path C:\Users\LLLLLL\Desktop\Ex Folder\

Comment: I assume that I was supposed to change C:\Temp\ with the directory all the files were in?

Comment: Yes.  Of course, if you were doing this regularly, we could build in a folder selection part...

Comment: I got it to work. I had to change myFileName, 4 to myFileName, 5

Comment: Would you be able to help me with another macro issue?

Comment: I can try.  What is it?  want to post it as another question?

Comment: Hello. Yes I already did. Here is the title of it. I belive you can probably locate it in my profile. "Extract Rows from spreadsheet and put into multiple spreadsheets based off of criteria"

Comment: LOL, now I see my mistake.  When I tested the code, I used a collection of PST files I had in Temp, so of course, right, 4 worked for me :)  Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to command prompt
2. Point to the folder location having the files
3. Type:  **ren *.xlsx  *-MN.xlsx**

This should add the suffix (-MN) to all xlsx files present in the folder

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you! :)

Comment: Hello I actually spoke too soon. This is what I get .. HIBS.xlsx-MN . I need it to be HIBS-MN.xlsx